# Some people hate noise. They should not live in the city. Connect two sentences with who. People who hate noise should not live in the city

Tags: grammar

> **Some** people hate noise. They should not live in the city.

Connect two sentences with **who**.

> People **who** hate noise should not live in the city.

Why the answer does not include the first word **some**?

Comment: Maybe because the 'they' in the second sentence refers to people who hate noise. If you write "Some people who hate noise should not live in the city.", that would mean there are people who hate noise, and some of these people who hate noise should not live in the city.

Comment: In second sentence, there are two meanings.                                                     The first meaning: People who hate noise should not live in the city.  The second meaning: Some of these people who hate noise should not live in the city. Are these your opinions?

Comment: Does the second sentence really have these two meanings???

Comment: @Mikiko Okay, it only has one meaning: there are people who hate noise, and some of these people who hate noise should not live in the city. I will remember it.

Comment: @Mikiko But can you tell me what  the difference is between two sentences: 'Some people who hate noise should not live in the city.' and 'Some of people who hate noise should not live in the city.'?

Comment: You already got an answer from a native English speaker, so I'm sure you don't need this anymore, but I was talking about a difference between "Poeple who hate noise should not live in the city." and "Some people who hate noise should not live in the city." My apology for the confusing comment.

Comment: @Mikiko Hello, does the second sentence really have these two meanings???  Do you think it has two meanings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The combined sentence doesn't include *some* because the second sentence doesn't include *some*.

> 1. Some people hate noise. *They* should not live in the city.
>   → People who hate noise should not live in the city.

Compare this to the following:

> 2. Some people hate noise. *Some of them* should not live in the city.
>   → Some people who hate noise should not live in the city.

---

The pronoun *they* refers to *everybody* who hates noise. It's only in the second version with *some of* ***them*** that all of the people who hate noise becomes divided into a yet-smaller group of people.

---

Both 1. and 2. can be expressed by the same, more general, sentence:

> Some people should not live in the city.

But that is leaving out important information.

Comment: Some people who hate noise should not live in the city.  Does this sentence have two meanings?  The first: (Some people) who hate noise should not live in the city.  The second: Some (people who hate noise should not live in the city).  Am I right?